# Please explain how in Xcode ,"func a" is in callee section of "func b" but "func b" isnt in caller section of "func a"

Tags: xcode

Please explain how in Xcode ,"func a" is in callee section "func b" but "func b" isnt in caller section of "func a".

For example i would option click ".run" in this function found in my scene:

```
func start(){
    whale.run()
}
```

and be brought to where it is declared in the whale class:

```
func run(){
    let animation = Whale.walkAnimationFrames
    let runanimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(animation, timePerFrame: 0.05)
    let repeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(runanimation)
    self.runAction(repeat)
}
```

I want to be able to determine all the locations were my function "run()" has been used and choose one

run is in the callee section of start... so i click on it(run) and go immediately to related files and callers... however start is not in the caller section of run... what am i missing. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> … I am unable to figure out how to navigate back …

Have you tried Navigate > Go Back?

Comment: hahah, yes the back button works, but that not really the problem. Im trying to navigate my project quickly and i need to be able to determine  all the locations where a function is being used.